# Solve $ x^2 = 2$ over $ F_5 $.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, primitive-roots

Since $ F_5 $ is isomorphic to $ \Bbb Z_5 $, I tried to solve this equation over $ \Bbb Z_5 $.

Since $ gcd(2,5)=1 $, $ \Bbb Z_5 $ contains a primitive $2$nd root of unity.

So if $ \omega $ is the primitive root of unity and $ \alpha $ is any root, then the roots would be $ \alpha $ and $\alpha \omega $.

Is this approach correct or is there some other way to solve this$?$

Comment: "If $a$ is a solution to $x^2 = 2$, then so is $-a$" would be the easy way to say it, but yes, $-1$ is the primitive root of unity so that's the same thing.

Comment: Yes. The primitive root of unity is 4 and -1 is equal to 4 modulo 5.

Comment: The solutions of that equation exist only in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$. And outside the subfield $\Bbb{F}_5$.

Answer (score 8):

Since $F_5$ is a field with only five elements, it is perhaps simplest to solve the equation by just trying each element.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2=x\iff x^2-x=x(x-1)=0$ Since it is a quadratic equation a coefficients in a field, there are just two solutions which are given by the last equality, (i. e. $1$ and $0$)

Comment: Note that this is true for all prime field $\mathbb F_p$

Comment: Wrong equation, it is $\,x^2 = 2,\,$ not $\,x^2 = x\ $

Comment: I am almost sure I have read $x^2=x$

Comment: That equation does not exist anywhere here. It's probably best to delete the answer to avoid confusing readers.